# Cannot move all files to new folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook to move 20% of the files in a folder to another folder, selecting them randomly. My code:

```
path_temp ='/media/Snaps/temp/'
path_valid_break ='/media/Snaps/valid/break/'
files = os.listdir(path_temp)
for x in range(int(len(files)*0.2)):
     index = random.randrange(0, len(files))
     shutil.move(path_temp + files[index], path_valid_break)
```

I have 1249 files in the initial folder. The code works and starts to move the files but stops after an arbitrary (so it seems) number of files (35 or 5 or 23,...) with error:

```
~/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/shutil.py in move(src, dst, copy_function)
    540         real_dst = os.path.join(dst, _basename(src))
    541         if os.path.exists(real_dst):
--> 542             raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
    543     try:
    544         os.rename(src, real_dst)

Error: Destination path '/media/Snaps/valid/break/snaps123211_-1.png' already exists
```

The target folder is empty when starting. The code does not always block on the same file, I cannot see a pattern.

Comment: probably because there's already a file with this name from a previous run. You could try to delete the file in the dest dir if already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Jean-François Fabre's answers it could be useful to point out that your code picks a random number for every loop, so it is possible that you are trying to copy the same file twice. To avoid this you can instead random shuffle the file list and pick the first 20%.

```
random.shuffle(files)
for thisfile in files[:int(len(files)*0.2)]:
    shutil.move(path_temp + thisfile, path_valid_break)
```

Comment: yes indeed, thanks @Hirabayashi, my random index was changing each time but i was not reading again the file list that was left over. Now I changed the code to re-read the content of the folder after each move and it's working. There is probably a faster way to do it, but it's fast enough for my purpose. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.move` tries to use `os.rename` first, to avoid copying then deleting the source (it's very fast). If it doesn't work (because not the same logical unit), then it tries to copy then delete the source file.

Here, the destination file already exists (from a previous run?). So `os.rename` fails with that particular reason (and doesn't try the second method)

If you don't care about the previous file in the destination folder, you could try to remove the file if exists:

```
if os.path.exists(path_valid_break):
   os.remove(path_valid_break)
shutil.move(path_temp + files[index], path_valid_break)
```

(`remove` could fail, but if it succeeds, the `move` command will succeed too)